# Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/CreationExtras$Key; in Android Library module UI Test

Tags: android, android-testing

#### Description

I'm trying to run an Android UI Test from a module, `:mylibrary`, that applies the `com.android.library` plugin. Right now, all of our Android UI tests are in our `:app` which is a `com.android.application` module. Also, the `:app` application module depends on the `:mylibrary` android library module. (The following diagram is an overly simplified representation of our dependency graph.)

[image]

When I introduce an Android UI Test in an android library module and run, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.CreationExtras$Key" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~IQ9A0iTcN9ysP1ynYkle2w==/com.example.ivan.test-EKcv8pjnvziFFyouy7OVag==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~IQ9A0iTcN9ysP1ynYkle2w==/com.example.ivan.test-EKcv8pjnvziFFyouy7OVag==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~IQ9A0iTcN9ysP1ynYkle2w==/com.example.ivan.test-EKcv8pjnvziFFyouy7OVag==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
```

This happens whether the UI tests are simple instrumented tests (annotated with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)`) or if the test is a `@HiltAndroidTest`.

#### What I've Tried

Since this looks like a dexing issue, I've tried adding

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled false
}
```

and I've tried filtering the class in question in proguard:

```
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; }
```

I've also tried adding the specific dependency to the module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewModel
}
```

I've also tried adding

```
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; }
```

to `multidex-config.pro` file as explained in the [keeping multidex properties](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle) section of Android Developer documentation.

#### Stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.CreationExtras$Key" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~IQ9A0iTcN9ysP1ynYkle2w==/com.example.ivan.test-EKcv8pjnvziFFyouy7OVag==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~IQ9A0iTcN9ysP1ynYkle2w==/com.example.ivan.test-EKcv8pjnvziFFyouy7OVag==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~IQ9A0iTcN9ysP1ynYkle2w==/com.example.ivan.test-EKcv8pjnvziFFyouy7OVag==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 23 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/CreationExtras$Key;
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleSupport.enableSavedStateHandles(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.<init>(ComponentActivity.java:305)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:108)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:94)
at com.example.ivan.MyLibraryActivity.<init>(MyLibraryActivity.kt:6)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1285)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.newActivity(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:817)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3578)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3842)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2252)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.CreationExtras$Key" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~IQ9A0iTcN9ysP1ynYkle2w==/com.example.ivan.test-EKcv8pjnvziFFyouy7OVag==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~IQ9A0iTcN9ysP1ynYkle2w==/com.example.ivan.test-EKcv8pjnvziFFyouy7OVag==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~IQ9A0iTcN9ysP1ynYkle2w==/com.example.ivan.test-EKcv8pjnvziFFyouy7OVag==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 23 more
```

Comment: Ivan did you find solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a version mismatch between test and app artifacts.

`CreationExtras` was added in [`androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-*:2.5.0`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.5.0) but my app was using `2.4`